# Best way to cast array (text[]) to record-type?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, array, record

PostgreSQL has the ability to create record types. A lot of operations like `regexp_match` return `text[]`. What is the most efficent way to go from `text[]` to a custom record type?

[Currently, I'm doing it quite explicitly,](https://github.com/houstondatavis/data-jam-february-2018/blob/master/sql/06_funcs.sql)

```
SELECT (a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6])::census.series_id
FROM census.alldata
CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_matches(series_id, '^(.{2})(.)(.*?)(.{4})(.{2})(.)$') AS t(a);
```

And, I'm wondering if there is a nicer way to do this than that. Ideally, I would just be able to cast `text[]` into any record type, and the coercion would take place under the hood. When I try this I get an error though,

```
SELECT a::census.series_id
FROM census.alldata
CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_matches(series_id, '^(.{2})(.)(.*?)(.{4})(.{2})(.)$') AS t(a);

ERROR:  cannot cast type text[] to census.series_id
LINE 1: SELECT a::census.series_id
```